# Why is a Dedekind complete totally ordered field compatible with multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(A,+,*,≤)$ be a Dedekind complete totally ordered field.

How do we use the above to prove that ${\forall}x,y,z\,{\in}\,A:x<y,0<z{\implies}x*z<y*z $?

Comment: Dedekind completeness isn't necessary here. Just note that $y-x>0$, so $(y-x)z>0$.

Comment: How do you formally prove that $y-x>0$?

Comment: You have $y>x$. Add $-x$ to both sides.

Comment: We know from the definition that $∀x,y,z\,∈\,A:x≤y{\implies}x+z≤y+z$. How do we get $∀x,y,z\,∈\,A:x<y{\implies}x+z<y+z$?

Comment: Suppose $x+z=y+z$. Then we also have $x+z+(-z)=y+z+(-z)$, so $x=y$. Hence, taking contrapositive, if there is a strict inequality between $x$ and $y$, then so is there between $x+z$ and $y+z$.